# How to scale Lambda when /tmp is reused?

Tags: amazon-web-services, scalability, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that reads from DynamoDB and creates a large file (~500M) in /tmp that finally uploaded to s3. Once uploaded the lambda clears the file from /tmp (since there is a high probability that the instance may be reused)

This function takes about 1 minute to execute, even if you ignore the latencies.

In this scenario, when i try to invoke the function again, in < 1m, i have no control if i will have enough space to write to /tmp. My function fails.

Questions:
1. What are the known work arounds in these kind of scenario?
(Potentially give more space in /tmp or ensure a clean /tmp is given for each new execution)
2. What are the best practices regarding file creation and management in Lambda?
3. Can i attach another EBS or other storage to Lambda for execution ?
4. Is there a way to have file system like access to s3 so that my function instead of using /tmp can write directly to s3?

Comment: I don't see why you NEED a file (or file system), especially considering that you're using FaaS/Amazon Lambda. Could you rewrite your code so that the DynamoDB output is streamed to S3 without writing it to disk?

Comment: There is a lot of processing that needs to be done.not just a simple dump from dynamo to s3

Comment: Maybe you're just hitting the limit (512M) then? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html It might help to work in-memory, or add a third service for temporary storage in between.

Comment: @usama not really, the best way is to clean up after you use it, else may be just clean before use.

Answer (score 12):

I doubt that two concurrently running instances of AWS Lambda will share /tmp or any other local resource, since they must execute in complete isolation. Your error should have a different explanation. If you mean, that a *subsequent* invocation of AWS Lambda reuses the same instance, then you should simply clear /tmp on your own.

In general, if your Lambda is a resource hog, you better do that work in an ECS container worker and use the Lambda for launching ECS tasks, as described [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/better-together-amazon-ecs-and-aws-lambda).

Comment: I have seen that the function is reused a lot. And have faced issues where the instance is reused. Which means the tmp folder is unavailable at that instance

Comment: This answer is correct.  Instances are often reused, **but not concurrently**.  Clean up your temp directory when the function finishes -- or just remove any files that are present when it starts (meaning after the handler is invoked, not during initialization, of course) -- and this should not be a problem. +1

Comment: This is only a _partial_ answer to the four questions listed and I'm actually interested in the answers to the _unanswered_ ones.

Comment: @usama ```rm -rf /tmp/*```

Comment: @Leon are you sure? [This exert](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/running-lambda-code.html) from the AWS states (of the /tmp dir) 'The directory content remains when the Execution Context is frozen, providing transient cache that can be used for multiple invocations'

Comment: @Peza Yes, I am sure. The context can be reused by a subsequent invocation of the *same AWS Lambda instance. Two different Lambda instances do not share the `/tmp` directory. You can also read [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016683/aws-lambda-and-java-concurrency/38041246#38041246)

Answer (score 5):

You are likely running into the [512 MB /tmp limit](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) of AWS Lambda.

You can improve your performance and address your problem by storing the file in-memory, since the memory limit for Lambda functions can go as high as [1.5 GB](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/50-increase-in-memory-capacity-for-aws-lambda-functions/).

Comment: The issue i was facing is not technically the limit of tmp size, since the containers are being reused, the tmp is not really empty when i get it, it has some stuff from previous executions.

Answer (score 5):

Starting March 2022, Lambda now supports **increasing `/tmp` directory's maximum size limit** up to **10,240MB**.
More information available [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-now-supports-up-to-10-gb-ephemeral-storage/).

Answer (score 0):

Now it is even easy, AWS storage can be increased to 10GB named Ephemeral Storage. It is available in general configuration of the AWS lambda functions.