# Are AWs Lambdas serially reusable in Java

Tags: java, aws-lambda

Are AWS Lambdas serially reusable and thread-safe?  In other words, can I use class fields to maintain state while the Lambda is running.  I don't intend to re-use the state.  Any field variables would be re-used and re-set at the next invocation.  I just want to make sure that my Lambda won't be executed by multiple threads at the same time.

Comment: [aws-lambda-and-java-concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016683/aws-lambda-and-java-concurrency)

Comment: That helps, but is doesn't seem very definitive for the question I'm answer, especially with all the varying opinions.  It sure looks like the answer is yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Lambda scales horizontally.  It will spin up multiple instances but a particular Lambda is only in use by a single caller at a particular time.  Multiple callers would get multiple Lambdas.

Comment: Sorry but do not you think that it is better to put some related links to the answer?