# timeout issue python aws lambda data copy from s3 to redshift

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

as far as I know AWS lambda will consider as fail if function taks over 3 seconds

```
def copy_to_redshift(cur, key):
    sql = '''
    copy <table_name> 
    from '<s3 bucket url>' 
    credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<..>;aws_secret_access_key=<..>' 
    json 'auto'
    ''' % (key)

    cur.execute(sql)
```

I use this code to load data from s3 to redshift. it is take over 3 seconds and I got this log from lambda

```
Task timed out after 3.00 seconds
```

How can I reduce this performance?

my s3 file size is 7M and have 50000 rows.

lucky my redshift could load successfully even lambda finish as fail and I think function doesn't need to wait until copy sql.

is it possible to just give sql and terminate function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS Lambda Task timed out after 6.00 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47594168/aws-lambda-task-timed-out-after-6-00-seconds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Lambda has a maximum timeout of 5 minutes. If your processing is not getting over within 3 seconds you can try to gradually increase that and see what the optimum timeout for your Lambda can be (obviously upto a max of 5 minutes)

Regarding "How can I reduce this performance", you can try increasing the memory footprint for your Lambda. This single memory control knob does 2 things

1. Increase the memory (RAM) available for your Lambda
2. Increase the CPU power available to your Lambda proportional to the memory

Combination of above 2 should hopefully resolve the problem

And yes if the Lambda issues the Redshift copy command before it times out then that Redshift operation will succeed irrespective of Lambda timing out