# How to copy the object in s3 from account A to Account B with updated object ownership to object A

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My code copies the object from Account A to Account B

```
import json
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement

    SOURCE_BUCKET = 'Bucket-A'
    DESTINATION_BUCKET = 'Bucket-B'

    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

    # Create a reusable Paginator
    paginator = s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')

    # Create a PageIterator from the Paginator
    page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=SOURCE_BUCKET)

    # Loop through each object, looking for ones older than a given time period
    for page in page_iterator:
        if "Contents" in page:
            for object in page['Contents']:
                if object['LastModified'] < datetime.now().astimezone() - timedelta(minutes=5):   # <-- Change time period here
                    print(f"Moving {object['Key']}")

                    # Copy object
                    s3_client.copy_object(
                        ACL='bucket-owner-full-control',
                        Bucket=DESTINATION_BUCKET,
                        Key=object['Key'],
                        CopySource={'Bucket':SOURCE_BUCKET, 'Key':object['Key']}
                    )

                    # Delete original object
                    s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=SOURCE_BUCKET, Key=object['Key'])
        else:
            print("No Contents key for page!")
```

The lambda function role policy is :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject*",
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:GetObject*",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:DeleteObject*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::Bucket-A/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-A"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-B/*"
        }
    ]
}


aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket bucket-b --key key1
{
    "Owner": {
        "DisplayName": "accountA",
        "ID": "MYIDA"
    },
    "Grants": [
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "DisplayName": "accountA",
                "ID": "MyIDA",
                "Type": "CanonicalUser"
            },
            "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
        },
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "DisplayName": "accountb",
                "ID": "MyIDB",
                "Type": "CanonicalUser"
            },
            "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I change the owner of the object while copying from Account A to account B to Account B

```
 {
        "Owner": {
            "DisplayName": "accountB",
            "ID": "MYIDB"
        },
```

Comment: Your code is correctly setting the ACL when performing the copy. The object is therefore owned by the AWS Account that owns the bucket, not a specific user.

Comment: No the object is owned by the account which is transferring the object i.e Accoun A, I want it to account b

Comment: If credentials from Account-A are used to copy an object to a bucket owned by Account-B, then specifying `ACL='bucket-owner-full-control'` will give control to Account-B. If credentials from Account-B are used to copy the object from Account-A to Account-B, then Account-B will own it (without needing the ACL).

Comment: if you see the get acl command it keeps owner as account A, and I am using the role attached to lambda. Shall I replace it with account B credentials?

Comment: It is always better to use credentials from the destination account, which avoids the ACL issues. Please note that this means that the bucket policy on the source bucket will need to be modified to allow `GetObject` access to the IAM Role or IAM User that is being used for the copy.

Comment: So I need to modify the bucket policy and what about the lambda role?

Comment: The bucket policy on Bucket-A needs to grant `GetObject` access to the IAM Role used by the Lambda function in Account-B.

Comment: the lambda function is in acc A

Comment: If the Lambda function is using credentials from Account-A then it needs to set `ACL='bucket-owner-full-control'` in the command that copies the file to Bucket-B.

Comment: that is already there but the bucket owner needs to be changed, thats what I want. I think if I use credentials from accountB then it will work

Comment: You mention "the bucket owner needs to be changed". Why is that? The bucket belongs to Account-B. Ownership of the **bucket** does not need to change.

Comment: But if you see the `aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket bucket-b --key key1` it gives me account A as owner for the object. I want the object owner to be account B

Comment: Does it? I didn't know about that. Is this a particular problem for you? If that's the case, then the only way to avoid it would be to "pull" the object into the bucket by using credentials from Account-B, rather than "pushing" from Account-A. If using `ACL='bucket-owner-full-control'`, then Bucket-B can do whatever it wishes to the object, the fact that is says the owner is something else won't really matter.

Comment: when the object moves to bucket-b and cloudfront tries to access the object I get 403 error. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-rest-api-cloudfront-error-403/ So you meant I should move the lambda function from account A to Account B , can I keep the credentials of account B and lambda function in Account A to solve the cproblem? What do you suggest?

Comment: Let's continue in chat, since this is heading somewhere different to your question: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214788/aws-chat

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to address your question first and then provide a better approach for the use case.

Firstly, as you have correctly identified, what you are looking for are Object ACL. Boto3 gives you a   <strike>way to retrieve and update Object ACLs and thus the object owners</strike>  way to retrieve Object ACLs and thus the object owners as well as update ACL. Read more about this in the official docs [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.ObjectAcl.put). To read about Object ACLs, you can refer to the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#CannedACL).

For reference, here's a sample Request Syntax:

```
response = object_acl.put(
    ACL='private'|'public-read'|'public-read-write'|'authenticated-read'|'aws-exec-read'|'bucket-owner-read'|'bucket-owner-full-control',
    AccessControlPolicy={
        'Grants': [
            {
                'Grantee': {
                    'DisplayName': 'string',
                    'EmailAddress': 'string',
                    'ID': 'string',
                    'Type': 'CanonicalUser'|'AmazonCustomerByEmail'|'Group',
                    'URI': 'string'
                },
                'Permission': 'FULL_CONTROL'|'WRITE'|'WRITE_ACP'|'READ'|'READ_ACP'
            },
        ],
        'Owner': {
            'DisplayName': 'string',
            'ID': 'string'
        }
    },
    GrantFullControl='string',
    GrantRead='string',
    GrantReadACP='string',
    GrantWrite='string',
    GrantWriteACP='string',
    RequestPayer='requester',
    VersionId='string'
)
```

Now coming to a better way to implement this. Have a look at AWS Cross Region Replication. Read more about it in the announcement post [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cross-region-replication-for-amazon-s3/) or refer to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication.html).

To use the description from the docs:

> Replication enables automatic, asynchronous copying of objects across Amazon S3 buckets. Buckets that are configured for object replication can be owned by the same AWS account or by different accounts. You can copy objects between different AWS Regions or within the same Region.

> Maintain object copies under different ownership — Regardless of who owns the source object, you can tell Amazon S3 to change replica ownership to the AWS account that owns the destination bucket. This is referred to as the owner override option. You can use this option to restrict access to object replicas.

Essentially you can use LifeCycle Policies and automate the whole process. You can also configure the destination objects to be created with a new Owner. With this you are offloading the management to AWS and also making the process reactive. In the long run, this will help you save costs both in terms of man-power costs and resource usage.

Comment: Cross region replication does not suffice my case. If you see my code, you will find that I want to move objects that are older than an hour. So after copying I should change the object ACL?

Comment: cant I do it while copying the object?

Comment: ACL being an Objects property, you need the object to be able to set it's ACL. Is there any specific concern you have around this or is it the code quality ?

Comment: just the code quality, so can you tell me how the code would look like, a snippet?

Comment: *"...retrieve and update Object ACLs and thus the object owners."* No.  Object ACL does not convey ownership.